# The $n^{th}$ derivative in change of variable

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, differential-operators, change-of-variable

I want to change variable $x$ in my differential equation to $t=g(x)$. I would like to create pattern for $n^{th}$ new derivative $\frac{d^ny}{dt^n}$ for any transformation depends on old derivatives $
\frac{dy}{dx},
\dots, \frac{d^ny}{dx^n}
$.

Can you tell me please if the patter or algorithm exists? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It would be more natural to study $x=f(t)$, as the original equation contains the variable $x$.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the [Faà di Bruno's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula). [This](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/252916819_Chain_Rules_for_Higher_Derivatives) paper gives some historical background for the formula and [this one](http://www.math.cmu.edu/~wn0g/noll/CHR.pdf) presents some connections to complex analysis and combinatorics.

Comment: I think this is what I want. Thank you very much